# How does OpenGL resolve a multisampled FBO-attached color buffer whose pixel format is integer-based?

Tags: opengl, integer, fbo, multisampling

Suppose I format a **`renderbuffer`** like so:

```
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, sampleCount, GL_R32UI, imageWidth, imageHeight);

where sampleCount >= 2.
```

And suppose I attach it to an FBO, draw some stuff into it, blit it to a non-multisampled FBO to resolve the multisampling, and finally call glReadPixels to get back some unsigned integers (one per pixel) from the resulting image.

What integers will I get?

Might some of them be a blend of multiple samples, or is only one sample per pixel chosen in this case (presumably because an integer-based format is not considered to be blendable in this context), with the other samples being discarded?  Or does something else happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 511 of the OpenGL 4.5 spec, under section 18.3.1 "Blitting Pixel Rectangles", it says (emphasis added):

> If the **read framebuffer is multisampled** (its effective value of SAMPLE_BUFFERS is one) and the draw framebuffer is not (its value of SAMPLE_BUFFERS is zero), the samples corresponding to each pixel location in the source are converted to a single sample before being written to the destination. filter is ignored. If the **source formats are integer types** or stencil values, a **single sample’s value is selected** for each pixel.

So it choses one sample per pixel, without specifying which of the samples.

Comment: The quote you've provided says that when blitting from a multi-sample source to a non-multi-sample destination, that the samples for each pixel are "converted" (which usually means "averaged out") before being written to the destination. Nowhere does it say that an arbitrary sample is chosen per pixel. I'm not sure where the OP gets the idea that integer formats are not blendable either. Correct me if I'm wrong here, but how else would you resolve a multisample buffer aside from averaging out the samples?